# Run a function if a div has an active class else run another function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get an if else statement that will allow me to run a function if the #selectedwhip div has the .active class. If it doesn't, I want it to run another function. I've just used the console to see if it will work but it only returns the else statement in the console.

The scenario is 3 images which act as links. By clicking the links they will add an active class to another div. By being active, an image will be inserted into the div. Clicking an image does add an active class to the div but it doesn't cause the if statement to log to the console.

Is there something that's preventing it from working?

jQuery

```
    $(".carbutton").click(function(){
      $("#selectedwhip").addClass("active");
    });

    $(function() {
      if ($("#selectedwhip").hasClass("active")) {
        console.log('active');
      }
      else {
        console.log('unactive');
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
  <div class="cars">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="section group trio-cars">
        <div class="col span_1_of_3 carbutton" id="carbutton">
        <a id="car1"><img src="img/frontleftbmw.jpg" width="100%"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3 carbutton" id="carbutton">
        <a id="car2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3 carbutton" id="carbutton">
        <a id="car3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100%"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
         <div class="stats-image" id="selectedwhip">
         </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That if statement only happens on page load (when the dom is ready) it doesn't happen at all after you do a click

Comment: Yes, because this function that checks it is running only when you start the page. Then, you click the `.carbutton`, which will add the class, but you won't be running the function again.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to run the if else statement constantly if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes. Make it a named function and then within your ready statement call the function. Then you can also call that same function on your button click.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a check function such as:

```js
function check() {
  if ($("#selectedwhip").hasClass("active")) {
    console.log('active');
  } else {
    console.log('unactive');
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(".carbutton").click(function() {
    $("#selectedwhip").addClass("active");
    check();
  });
});
```

---

Just noticed you have duplicate IDs `carbutton` and that makes it as a invalid markup creation. Every ID should have to be unique.

Comment: This is what I would do. And if you want to also check on ready also call the all you need to do is also call the check(); function above the .carbutton click function. That way you are covered for ready and click

Answer (score 0):

you have to be clear what do you want to do and when. because you're just executing a function immediately the page is ready

```
$(function() {
  if ($("#selectedwhip").hasClass("active")) {
    console.log('active');
  }
  else {
    console.log('unactive');
  }
});
```

the above code will check if selectedwhip it has active class in the first load of the page. 
you have to attach this conditional to an event

Comment: I've added the click event into it now, the aim is to insert an image into the #selectedwhip div when the .carbutton is active